# Dynamic table rows and id ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I tried to create dynamic rows in my table
The code:

```
    <tbody>
                <%for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                  {%>
                <tr>
                    <td><%dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();//Email%></td>
                    <td><%dt.Rows[i][4].ToString();//ID%></td>
                    <td>
                        <center><asp:Button ID="EditUser" runat="server" Text="Edit" class="btn btn-info" /></center>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <center><asp:Button ID="RemoveUser" runat="server" Text="X" class="btn btn-danger" /></center>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <center><asp:Button ID="SendPasswordUser" runat="server" Text="Send Password" class="btn btn-success" /></center>
                    </td>
                    <%}%>
                </tr>
```

And whats happend-the text isn't written into the table.

The another problem is when I tried to create dynamic ID's to the buttons (ID="EditUser<%i%>"):

```
    <center><asp:Button ID="EditUser<%i%>" runat="server" Text="Edit" class="btn btn-info" /></center>
```

I got an error that the name is incorrect because <%I%> (from Users.aspx.designer.cs file):

```
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button EditUser<%i%>;
```

How can I fix it?Thanks!

Update: 
I fixed the first problem.

```
    <td><%Response.Write(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());//Email%></td>
```

I just need help with the ID's problem.

Comment: why are you using scrip-lets in the last part of your code?

Comment: what do you mean? <%}%> ?

Comment: i mean in  protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button EditUser<%i%>;

Comment: This is from Users.aspx.designer.cs, I fix it now in the post:)

Comment: You tagged this as Razor, but you appear to be using web controls from Web Forms. The two are not compatible, you'll need to pick one or the other. And when you need a high degree of control over the generated HTML, I suggest Razor.

Comment: Ok,i fixed the problem..just add Response.Write(....),I just need to fix the id's problem

Comment: You should use a GridView to do this.

Comment: Can you give an example?